# AnyChart, RangeBar Labels Overlapping?

Tags: charts, anychart

i am doing a rangebar with using anychart.(I am not an expert) My problem is that, labels are long and they are overlapping. **Values are in the same series**, **so i cannot use different style** to overcome this.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives for a solution of this problem:

1. It is possible to limit the number of characters using maxChar keyword. Please take a look at this article:
   http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/index.html?label-text-formatting.html#maxChar
2. use the tooltips to display this information

Also about different styles: you can create the style and apply it to a point, not only to a series:

```
<point name="Point 1" y="4123" style="Style 1" />
```